# GROUP BY MONTH gives wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get unique products views grouped by month using the following query

```
SELECT
  Month(timestamp)           AS 'month',
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitor_id) AS 'unique'
FROM productviews pv INNER JOIN products p ON pv.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.vendor_id = 8 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018
GROUP BY month(timestamp);
```

And I am getting

```
+---------+--------+
| month   | unique |
+---------+--------+
|    1    |  3     |
+---------+--------+
|    2    |  10    |
+---------+--------+
|    3    |  2     |
+---------+--------+
|    4    |  4     |
+---------+--------+
```

But the total number of unique product views is less than the sum of the previous query

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT pv.visitor_id)
FROM productviews pv INNER JOIN products p ON pv.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.vendor_id = 8 AND year(timestamp) = 2018

+---------+
|  count  |
+---------+
|    16   |
+---------+
```

Is it the right way to use group by month? Or Do I miss something?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you have some overlap with `visitor_id` and each _month_. In the first query, visitors are unique per month. In the second, it's across the entire year so the sum will be the same or smaller

Comment: I guess it is not the cause, but in the first query you use `DISTINCT visitor_id ` instead `DISTINCT pv.visitor_id`...

Comment: @DaltonCézane probably not important. If the column's table was ambiguous, MySQL would throw an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query is OK.

Because a visitor can have been visiting more than one month.

Comment: Is there any proposal to get the true query for this?
month name, number of unique visitor for this month

Comment: But your queries are both correct. Why would it be wrong? And what do you want insterad?

Comment: When a client investigates the numbers, he will find a difference between the total and the visit per day. maybe it is still not clear to me

Comment: Think about a visitor that is visiting january and february. He is in both month counts. So he is counted twice if you add this together. But If you count the visitors of the complete year he will be counted only once. That is the difference.

Answer (score 6):

If a visitor viewed a product in 2 different months, then the first query will count it twice, since the `visitor_id` will be unique within those two months. However, the 2nd query will count these views only once, since the `visitor_id` is duplicated across the entire year.

So, nothing wrong with the results of either of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

It’s clear, if you count the distinct products without dates, you get 16.
However, if you count the distinct products by month, you can have the same product in different months, so the final number won’t match.
If you just count (without distinct) the final number is gonna be the same
I.E. The count distinct for fruits are 3, orange, apple, banana. If I count distinct fruits by month I can have orange and apple in January, orange and banana in February, orange, apple and banana in March...